# FancyBox for WordPress not working any more

Tags: wordpress

My FancyBox for WordPress plugin stopped working. I can not see any problem with the plugin directly there are some errors with JavaScript from the theme but I have no idea how to fix them.

Here is the site: http://pomorie.bg/

P.S. I have not updated my theme or my plugins the FancyBox just stopped one day....

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking questions, it is imperative that you include all your information in your question (i.e. make sure to add your error messages to the question itself)

Answer (score 0):

When I checked your site, there were no errors in the console. If you saw a `net::ERROR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`, this is most likely an error caused by your ad blocker; it's nothing to worry about. There also do not appear to be any visual deformities. I cannot see anything wrong, please specify further

Comment: The problem is that FancyBox for Wordpres  is enabled and loaded in the page code but it does not work. It was working like 2 days before. When you press on picture they just open as simple image file view and before that when the plugin was working they pop up in lightbox(fancybox).http://pomorie.bg/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5/

Comment: The error I get is TypeError: a(...).data(...).off is not a function
a.fn.fancybox()
jquery.fancybox.js:18
<anonymous>
%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5:96
.ready()
jquery.min.js:26
L()
jquery.min.js:33

Comment: That appears to be a problem with (1) FancyBox, or (2) how you're using it. I would consult with their documentation